# Is there any controls available for star rating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rating, fractions

Is there any controls available for star rating in ios ? So i can use that in UITableviewCell ??

I know there are some open open source controls like DYRating etc.. But iam not able to add it in tableview cell .

Comment: Look at this http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view

Comment: Bhargavi: but i need to add that in uitableviewcell  so each row i can give input to that star ,then it will display the star corresponding to rating

Comment: Have you tried with CustomCells creation?

Comment: i didnt get u? can u pls expln?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check the ASStar rating .

Add the control directly to your view controller  or you can add into your cell .

And here is  [github link](http://github.com/yggg/ASStarRatingView).

Comment: how to get the star count,,,,,,,

Answer (score 19):

I recommend [HCSStarRatingView](https://github.com/hugocampossousa/HCSStarRatingView). It is native-looking and it also supports `IB_DESIGNABLE` and `IBInspectable`.

[image: HCSStarRatingView]

Answer (score 8):

Take a look, it should suit you just fine:

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=star+rating

Comment: Its  nice but difficult to implement inside tableviewcell

Answer (score 5):

Note: This is a "DISPLAY ONLY" one.
[image: STARS]

I took a different approach here, I created a label with attributed string using a font with stars, you can check my category here. I used "SS Pika" font,

```
#import "NSMutableAttributedString+Stars.h"

@implementation NSMutableAttributedString (Stars)

+ (NSAttributedString *)starWithRating:(CGFloat)rating
                            outOfTotal:(NSInteger)totalNumberOfStars
                          withFontSize:(CGFloat) fontSize{
    UIFont *currentFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SS Pika" size:fontSize];
    NSDictionary *activeStarFormat = @{
                                           NSFontAttributeName : currentFont,
                                           NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]
                                           };
    NSDictionary *inactiveStarFormat = @{
                                             NSFontAttributeName : currentFont,
                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor]
                                             };

    NSMutableAttributedString *starString = [NSMutableAttributedString new];

    for (int i=0; i < totalNumberOfStars; ++i) {
        //Full star
        if (rating >= i+1) {
            [starString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                               initWithString:@"\u22C6 " attributes:activeStarFormat]];
        }
        //Half star
        else if (rating > i) {
            [starString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                               initWithString:@"\uE1A1 " attributes:activeStarFormat]];
        }
        // Grey star
        else {
            [starString appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                               initWithString:@"\u22C6 " attributes:inactiveStarFormat]];
        }

    }
    return starString;
}
@end
```

USAGE:

```
self.ratingLabel.attributedText = [NSMutableAttributedString starWithRating:rating outOfTotal:5 withFontSize:9.0f];
```

Here is the SWIFT Version

```
extension NSMutableAttributedString{

    func starWithRating(rating:Float, outOfTotal totalNumberOfStars:NSInteger, withFontSize size:CGFloat) ->NSAttributedString{


        let currentFont = UIFont(name: "<USE UR FONT HERE>", size: size)!

        let activeStarFormat = [ NSFontAttributeName:currentFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()];

        let inactiveStarFormat = [ NSFontAttributeName:currentFont, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.lightGrayColor()];

        let starString = NSMutableAttributedString()

        for(var i = 0; i < totalNumberOfStars; ++i){

            if(rating >= Float(i+1)){
                // This is for selected star. Change the unicode value according to the font that you use
                starString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\u{22C6} ", attributes: activeStarFormat))
            }
            else if (rating > Float(i)){
                // This is for selected star. Change the unicode value according to the font that you use
                starString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\u{E1A1} ", attributes: activeStarFormat))
            }
            else{
                // This is for de-selected star. Change the unicode value according to the font that you use
                starString.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "\u{22C6} ", attributes: inactiveStarFormat))
            }
        }

        return starString
    }
}
```

USAGE:

```
starLabel.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString().starWithRating(3.5, outOfTotal: 5, withFontSize: 8.0)
starLabelFull.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString().starWithRating(5, outOfTotal: 5, withFontSize: 8.0)
starLabelZero.attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString().starWithRating(0, outOfTotal: 5, withFontSize: 8.0)
```

Answer (score 5):

**`Swift3`**

https://github.com/marketplacer/Cosmos

- **install pod**

  `target 'TargetName' do`

  `pod 'Cosmos'`
- **Install pod file with this command `pod install`**
- **Put a simple UIView in your storyboard and give the class name as `CosmosView` and Module name `Cosmos`**

[image]

**HERE YOU CAN ACCESS THE ATTRIBUTES**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can check following controls from Cocoacontrols.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/star-rating-view

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/scrratingview

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/amratingcontrol

Answer (score 3):

I just wrote this simple UIView subclass that draws stars rating from 0 to 5 including half stars. You can set the color with tintColor property and set the rating in interface editor. View width should be set to 5 * height.

[image: star rating]

```
class StarsView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var rating: Double = 5.0 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }

    func starPath(size: CGFloat, full: Bool) -> UIBezierPath {
        let fullPoints = [CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.03), CGPoint(x: 0.61, y: 0.38), CGPoint(x: 0.99, y: 0.38), CGPoint(x: 0.68, y: 0.61), CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: 0.97), CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.75), CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 0.97), CGPoint(x: 0.32, y: 0.61), CGPoint(x: 0.01, y: 0.38), CGPoint(x: 0.39, y: 0.38)].map({ CGPoint(x: $0.x * size, y: $0.y * size) })
        let halfPoints = [CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.03), CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.75), CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 0.97), CGPoint(x: 0.32, y: 0.61), CGPoint(x: 0.01, y: 0.38), CGPoint(x: 0.39, y: 0.38)].map({ CGPoint(x: $0.x * size, y: $0.y * size) })
        let points = full ? fullPoints : halfPoints
        let starPath = UIBezierPath()
        starPath.move(to: points.last!)
        for point in points {
            starPath.addLine(to: point)
        }
        return starPath
    }

    func starLayer(full: Bool) -> CAShapeLayer {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = starPath(size: bounds.size.height, full: full).cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = tintColor.cgColor
        return shapeLayer
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let sublayers = layer.sublayers
        for sublayer in sublayers ?? [] {
            sublayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        for i in 1...5 {
            if rating >= Double(i) - 0.5 {
                let star = starLayer(full: rating >= Double(i))
                star.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(bounds.size.height * CGFloat(i - 1), 0, 0)
                layer.addSublayer(star)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/hugocampossousa/HCSStarRatingView. it easy to implement this. just write down these lines of code.
Create IBOutlet HCSStarRatingView for in .h file an create one string for storing the rating value.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet HCSStarRatingView *starRatingView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *ratingStr;
```

in .m file write down these lines

```
self.starRatingView.maximumValue = 5;
self.starRatingView.minimumValue = 0;
self.starRatingView.value = 0;
self.starRatingView.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
self.starRatingView.allowsHalfStars = YES;
self.starRatingView.emptyStarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-empty"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
self.starRatingView.filledStarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart-full"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
[self.starRatingView addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)didChangeValue:(HCSStarRatingView *)sender {
   NSLog(@"Changed rating to %.1f", sender.value);
  ratingStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f",sender.value];
  if([hostRatingStr isEqualToString:@"-0.0"]){
      self.ratingLbl.text = @"0.0";
  }else{
      self.ratingLbl.text = hostRatingStr;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/shantaramk/RatingView.

It effortless to implement this. just follow below steps:

**Set Star View IBOutlet**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var rateView: StarRateView!
```

**Prepare Star Rate View**

```
func setupStarRateView() {
    self.rateView.delegate = self
    self.rateView.maxCount = 5
    self.rateView.fillImage = UIImage(named: "fill_star")!
    self.rateView.emptyImage = UIImage(named: "empty_star")!
}
```

**Adopt Rate View Delegate**

```
extension RateServiceViewController: RatingViewDelegate {

func updateRatingFormatValue(_ value: Int) {
    print("Rating : = ", value)
    }
}
```

Comment: When scroll the table star display will not work correctly. please check it and possible then add tableview then check it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah there are many libraries which you can use to make such controls like cosmos [Cosmos library for rating control](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos/)

if you want something like that looks like rating graph (like the one in image)then you can see 
  this repo in github [Rating graph view in iOS](https://github.com/nikeshkrjha/StarRatingControl)

[image]

Comment: can i get this in objective c?

Comment: really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is whole numbers of stars, you can use a simple String Array and use it to set the text property of a UILabel.

```
let ratingsDisplay = [
    "★☆☆☆☆",
    "★★☆☆☆",
    "★★★☆☆",
    "★★★★☆",
    "★★★★★"
]

let rating = 4
let label = UILabel()
label.text = ratingsDisplay[rating - 1]
```

Make sure you set the font of the UILabel to one which displays the black and white stars at the same size. Many but not all do.